OaUTH Request fails vb.net vb
It's my 1st time using oAuth2.
I keep getting this error after about almost a minute.
Count = 1
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146233088
HelpLink: Nothing
InnerException: {"A task was canceled."}
InnerExceptions: Count = 1
Message: "One or more errors occurred."
Source: "mscorlib"
StackTrace: "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)" & vbCrLf & "   
at FMS_FR2022.Tforce.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\dan\source\repos\FMS-FR2022\Tforce.aspx.vb:line 50"
TargetSite: {TResult GetResultCore(Boolean)}

The code I'm using is:
    Dim clientId As String = "b9e10494-6251-4b1c-854f-a5d03c34c027"
    Dim clientSecret As String = "am sending in actual secret"
    Dim credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, clientSecret)
    Dim headerValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials))

    Dim content = New FormUrlEncodedContent(New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
                                        {"client_id", clientId},
                                        {"client_secret", clientSecret},
                                        {"grant_type", "client_crdentials"},
                                        {"scope", "https://tffproduction.onmicrosoft.com/04cc9749-dbe5-4914-b262-d866b907756b/.default"}
                                        })
    Dim requestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ca4f5969-c10f-40d4-8127-e74b691f95de/oauth2/v2.0/token")
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", headerValue)
    requestMessage.Content = content

    Dim returnedtoken As String = requestMessage.Headers.Authorization.Parameter

    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    Dim task = client.SendAsync(requestMessage)



    Try
        Dim response = task.Result
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
        Dim responseBody As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errmsg As String = ex.Message
    End Try

I work solo and could use another set of eyes. Been at this for hours trying to find a good working example etc..  any help would be appreciated.
code is failing at Try Block "task.Result"
Thanks

Is there a particular reason that you're using task.Result instead of using Await?  Have you tried debugging and inspecting the inner exception when the exception is raised?  It looks like an OperationCanceledException which is surprising to me because I don't see an obvious cancelation point.

Craig  -  I'm actually working from an example I found that had Task.Result.  Have never used await before. Can you point me to an example?  Thanks

What context is this in?  Windows app, console app, server/webpage, other?

Craig,  Sorry I didn't mention this: VS 2022 VB webpage  aspx.

I'm pretty sure that in a server context, it's most appropriate to use Async and Await instead of Result.  There should be a lot of resources on how to do it, it looks like the online help under topic "Asynchronous programming with Async and Await (Visual Basic)" has discussion as well as links to other potentially useful articles.

Craig, Ok I'll go searching for the Async and Await articles ..
